# How to concatenate in Excel formula with string of relative number of characters?

Tags: excel, concatenation

Column A are vendor names and column B are their payment terms.

[image: Example]

As you can see, the cells of the two fields have varying amounts of characters.

I want to concatenate the two fields, but I want the amount of spaces between the two to vary (to match a total cell character length I specify), so the final concatenation is the same length for all cells.

Specifically, the longest concatenation is 14 characters, so I want to put additional spaces in the other concatenations so all cells have a net concatenation length of 14 characters.

Column F is an example of the result I'm looking for

Comment: Updated to show what I want in column F

Comment: The issue is with the fonts,  Now that you have column F the way you want change the fonts and they will not line up anymore.  The easiest way is with a Monospaced type font and the formula in my answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this:

```
=CONCATENATE(A2,REPT(" ",14 - LEN(A2)-LEN(B2)),B2)
```

This will give you the required 14 characters, but I suspect that you want the ends to line up, so it looks pretty.  You will need to format the cells into a Monospaced type font like; Courier, Courier New, Lucida Console, Monaco, or Consolas.

Comment: Perfect--I was unaware of the REPT() function.  Additionally, I noticed the inconsistent character spacing as I created my end result, but didn't realize Office has monospaced fonts.  Changed to Lucida Console it's just what I was looking for

Comment: can be even shorter   `=A2&REPT(" ",14-LEN(A2&B2))&B2`

Comment: @StevenMartin you are correct.  And depending on for whom I am developing the page I will use either.  If it was just a sheet that only I was going to use I would use one like yours, if it was to be reviewed and used by others I tend to use the concatenate function, because it trips them up. They have no idea what it is.:)